# find command in for loop does not list all the files

Tags: bash, macos, variables, for-loop, find

i made a script, which lists everysingle file in the current directory and subdirectory and gives me the md5sum from the head and tail (with offset) of this file and saves it into a .txt file.

i made this with pipes, so i wasn't able to redirect a variable, which has been declared before by userinput. So i changed my script to a for loop. 
Problem now: it doesn't list all the files, but only one. And it seems to do this randomely. Why doesn't it list all the files like before?

I even tryed **.* and ./* and so on. I use a macbookpro mac os 10.13.6. I onced installed something so i could use linux commands aswell for example like tree etc...

any help is appreciated! I have no clue whatelse i can do.

## old code in which the variable wasn't redirected:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Wie heißt die Festplatte?
read varname
echo Los gehts! 

before=$(date +%s)

find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f -exec bash -c 'h=`tail -n +50000 "{}" | head -c 1000 | md5`;\
             t=`tail -c 51000 "{}" | head -c 1000 | md5`;\
             echo "$varname {} ; $h ; $t"' \;> /Users/Tobias/Desktop/$varname.txt

after=$(date +%s)

echo Das hat: $(((after - $before)/60)) Minuten bzw $(((after - $before))) Sekunden gedauert
```

## new code in which it doesn't list all the files but only one :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Wie heißt die Festplatte?
read varname
echo Los gehts! 

before=$(date +%s)

for i in $( find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f ); do
h=$(tail -n +50000 $i | head -c 1000 | md5)
t=$(tail -c 51000 $i | head -c 1000 | md5)
echo "$varname; $i ; $h ; $t" > /Users/Tobias/Desktop/$varname.txt
done 

after=$(date +%s)

echo Das hat: $(((after - $before)/60)) Minuten bzw $(((after - $before))) Sekunden gedauert
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the file in each iteration of the loop. Use the append mode instead:

```
echo "$varname; $i ; $h ; $t" >> /Users/Tobias/Desktop/"$varname".txt
#                             ~~
```

or redirect the output of the whole loop:

```
    echo "$varname; $i ; $h ; $t"
done  > /Users/Tobias/Desktop/"$varname".txt
```

Comment: unfortunately, both variants give empty txt files but print the output of the loop into the shell.

Comment: Then your shell is severely broken.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output of the entire loop, not each `echo` statement, which overwrites the file each time.

```
for i in $( find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f ); do
    h=$(tail -n +50000 $i | head -c 1000 | md5)
    t=$(tail -c 51000 $i | head -c 1000 | md5)
    echo "$varname; $i ; $h ; $t"
done > /Users/Tobias/Desktop/$varname.txt
```